Atlases and Immersion
Good evening,
I am getting a bit confused in my studies of differential geometry. My question is: can I define an atlas for a manifold that is seen as a subspace of $ \mathbb{R}^n $?
For example, I know that the parametrization of the torus is given by:
$$
X(u,v)= \left( (R+r\cos(2\pi u))\cos(2\pi v), (R+r\cos(2\pi u))\sin(2\pi v), \sin(2\pi u) \right).
$$
By carefully choosing some subsets of the torus and paying attention to the inverse of the parametrization, I could indeed find an atlas in this way correct? .
This atlas corresponds to maps between $ \mathbb{R}^2  $and a subset of $ T^2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3 $, rather than to the "topological" space of $ T^2 $ as a square with the sides identified. Instead, it is related to its graphical representation in $ \mathbb{R}^3 $.

Yes, but how are you presented with the submanifold in general? Are you asking only about the torus? Your parametrization is, however, sloppy; what is the domain?

I am doing a general relativity course we are using some notions of differential geometry but I did not get a proper introduction with submanifolds, I saw something on a course of calculus but was always restricted to $\mathbb{R^n}$. My knowledge at the moment is very  fragmented. As for the parametrization ye I did not think about it too much I will look it better tomorrow morning, on top of my head I think I will need to work it out a little better because I have overlapping of values when for example when I consider $(u,v) =(0,0)$ and $(u,v) =(1,1)$ because I am describing  the same point?

Submanifolds of $\Bbb R^n$ is an excellent way to learn manifolds the first time. If you’re given them explicitly (covered by parametrizations that are homeomorphisms), then the inverse of a parametrization gives a chart. If you’re given them implicitly (by equations, so that the implicit function theorem applies), then locally they are represented by graphs, and projection onto the graph coordinate plane gives a chart.

Thank you so much I was getting so confused between the "topological" definitions of manifolds and the one related with $ \mathbb{R^n} $.
